# How to extract std::string (s) from a character array with embedded nulls

Tags: c++

I have a character array of known length with embedded nulls; there is no ending null.

```
const char * raw = "text1\0\0text2\0\0\0text3\0more text";
```

Doing this

```
std::string clean(raw);
```

Gives me just the first string (`"text1"`) however, I want the entire raw string.

I want multiple strings. In this particular case there are 4 string inside `raw.`

Comment: Don't just tack on more and more corrections to the question - *rewrite* it so that it becomes a single, concise, clear question.

Comment: @Kerrek SB I thought std::string (s) in the title would be clear but I guess not. But I also said my attempt give me one string, I want them all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without knowing the actual size of the string literal you will not do the task.
If you know the size then you can use constructor

```
basic_string(const charT* s, size_type n, const Allocator& a = Allocator());
```

or the corresponding method `assign`

Here the second parameter specifies the number of characters of s that will be copied in the string.

If the length is know then you can write simply

```
std::string clean( raw, n );
```

or

```
std::string clean;
clean.assign( raw, n );
```

EDIT: As you changed your original message then I will append my post. You can split the literal the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    const char * s = "text1\0\0text2\0\0\0text3\0more text";
    size_t n = 30;
    std::istringstream is( std::string( s, 30 ) );

    std::vector<std::string> v;
    std::string word;
    while ( std::getline( is, word, '\0' ) ) if ( !word.empty() ) v.push_back( word );

    for ( const std::string &s : v ) std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

The output is

```
text1
text2
text3
more text
```

If you have four different strings you can write

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    const char * s = "text1\0\0text2\0\0\0text3\0more text";
    size_t n = 30;
    std::istringstream is( std::string( s, 30 ) );

    std::string word1, word2, word3, word4;
    while ( std::getline( is, word1, '\0' ) && word1.empty() );
    while ( std::getline( is, word2, '\0' ) && word2.empty() );
    while ( std::getline( is, word3, '\0' ) && word3.empty() );
    while ( std::getline( is, word4, '\0' ) && word4.empty() );

    for ( const std::string &s : { word1, word2, word3, word4 } ) std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Can you show how I can extract the 4 strings separately?

Comment: This is the closest to what I want so far

Comment: I prefer your first version because the count of strings in the array may not be known. I am trying to decide how your solution compares to Praetorian in terms of efficiency

Comment: @user841550: don't fret the small stuff.

Answer (score 4):

If you can change the type of `raw` from `const char *` to `const char[]` then you can construct the string using a pair of iterators

```
const char raw[] = "text1\0\0text2\0\0\0text3\0more text";
std::string clean(std::begin(raw), std::end(raw));
```

Otherwise you'll need to provide the length of the string literal to the `std::string` constructor.

```
std::string clean(raw, length);
```

---

To answer the edited question about how to extract the 4 null character delimited strings from the string literal, here's a loop that'll do the job

```
std::vector<std::string> tokens;
std::string::size_type pos, lastPos = 0;
while(pos < clean.length())
{
    // find next delimiter
    pos = clean.find_first_of('\0', lastPos);
    if(pos == std::string::npos) {
        // we've reached the end of the string, so get remaining
        pos = clean.length();
    }

    // if not empty add it to the vector
    if(pos != lastPos) tokens.push_back(clean.substr(lastPos, pos - lastPos));
    // increment to next character
    lastPos = pos + 1;
}
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bdfe7a94c3defb8d)

Comment: +1 for what seems to be the only sane answer :-)

Comment: This gives me one string. I was hoping to extract each string individually.

Comment: @user841550: That's because you wrote an exceptionally unclear question. Why didn't you say what you actually wanted?

Comment: @user841550 Everyone, including myself, took *I want them all* to mean you want the entire string literal in a single `std::string`. So you want 4 `std::string` objects?

Comment: @Praetorian. Yes I want all individual strings objects embedded in the array

Answer (score 2):

`std::string` has a [constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) that takes a `const char *` and a count. You must determine how many characters are in the string you want to copy, since you can't use the usual convention of a  null terminator.

Comment: @KerrekSB footnote 4 on the link I gave in the word "constructor".

Answer (score 1):

since there is no ending null you must know the size in some other way.

Given the known size, just use [the string constructor that takes a pointer to first char, and a size](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string).

A `std::string` can contain null values.

Comment: Why is there no ending null? It's right there, at the end...

Comment: @KerrekSB: With embedded nulls a single automatically added null at the end, is not an ending null. Because it cannot be used to detect the end. An ending null for such a string (in the sense I think Vlad meant) is a null placed at the end by the programmer, followed by the automatically generated null.

Comment: Oh, not "Vlad" but "user841550" or "the OP". Sorry.

Comment: And additionally I posted incorrect code. Now rolled back. Coffee.

Answer (score 1):

You can go:

```
std::string(clean, clean + 30);
```

It would be better if you store the string in an array (or a `#define`), then you can check its length programmatically, e.g.

```
char const raw[] = "text1\0\0text2\0\0\0text3\0more text";
std::string(raw, raw + sizeof raw - 1);
```

Comment: also, consider using `vector<char>` since this is not really a string.

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behavior. The "\0" is being understood as end of string. If you try to pritnf you raw variable with "%s" format you will get the same output - "text1". If you want the whole string this is what you should do:

```
const char * raw = "text1\\0\\0text2\\0\\0\\0text3\\0more text";
```

So, before passing it to an std::string constructor you can write another routine which appends an extra '\'.

Comment: This will change the string to not contain embedded nulls, I don't think this is what he wanted

Comment: well then maybe he should store in an std::stringstream instead? i don't know..